# How to find all integer solutions of $p^2+q^2=((2q+1)^2+q+1)^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$$p^2+q^2=((2q+1)^2+q+1)^2+1$$
How do I find integer solutions to this equation? I've already found $(p,q)=(11,1)$. How do I go about finding new ones?

Comment: $p=11$ ; $q=1$ This result will come?

Comment: $(1,-1)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Both p and q must be odd. Since q = 1 is a successful candidate, try some larger odds.

Comment: For $|q|\le 10^7$ there are no further solutions (Python checked it for me).

Comment: Since someone else (Fundamental) added the diophantine-equations tag, I suppose it's worth saying here for the OP's benefit that there's [no algorithm for solving them in general](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html).

Comment: And in particular there's no algorithm for solving quartic ones (4th powers) like this one... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html

Answer (score 3):

For $q \geq 21,$
$$ (4q^2 + 5 q + 1)^2 < p^2 < (4q^2 + 5q + 2)^2  $$
because
$$ q \geq 21 \Longrightarrow 41 q^2 > 40 q^2 + 20 q + 5  $$
Therefore 
$$ (4q^2 + 5 q + 1) < p < (4q^2 + 5q + 2)  $$
and $p$ cannot be an integer.

Should be something similar for negative $q.$

Yes, 
$$ q \leq -3 \Longrightarrow 0 < 7 q^2 + 20 q + 5,  $$
so both sides of the inequality work. Also, we get the necessary $4 q^2 + 5 q> 0$ when $q \leq -3.$

Here is page 268 in Mordell's book, *Diophantine Equations*. He gives the few examples where all solutions can be found (but no inequalities apply) in the following pages.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this method may be generally used to show that $p^2 = aq^4 + bq^3 + cq^2 + dq + e$ has a finite number of solutions. Well, for suitably chosen constants, $a>0$ etc.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, only if $a$ is a square do we get specific bounds and can there find all solutions. Finiteness, but without specific bounds, is  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem  and is discussed from the viewpoint of Diophantine equations in Mordell's book.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose it's also worth mentioning here that the equation $ax^m=by^n+c$ [is conjectured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai%27s_conjecture) to have a finite number of solutions for $(n,m)\neq (2,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}p^2+q^2&=((2q+1)^2+q+1)^2+1\\\implies p^2+q^2&=16q^4+40q^3+41q^2+20q+5 \\\implies p^2&=16q^4+40q^3+40q^2+20q+5\end{align}$$

So for an integer $q$ if $16q^4+40q^3+40q^2+20q+5$ is a perfect square, then you will get integer solutions for your equation.

- $q=1\implies16q^4+40q^3+40q^2+20q+5=121=11^2$
- $q=-1\implies16q^4+40q^3+40q^2+20q+5=1=1^2$

So $(11,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are solutions, others may exist.

Comment: How do you show there are no other perfect square solutions?

Comment: where did i tell that?

Comment: You listed two solutions. I assumed that you believed those were the only ones.

Comment: no, those are solutions. checking whether other ones exist or not. well as in the comments below the question nothing revealed till now.